# mod_rewrite in each vhost with wildcard subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

**:: EDIT ::**

How to setup wildcard subdomains and then rewrite the adress?

### directory structure

```
/var/www/domain.com        // .htaccess with rewrite rules is placed here
/var/www/domain.com/_admin
/var/www/domain.com/_admin/tst
/var/www/domain.com/_files
/var/www/domain.com/_mysql
```

### .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^(admin|files|mysql)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      !^/_(admin|files|mysql)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$               /_%1/$1 [L]
```

when you request `http://admin.domain.com/tst` the adress is rewritten to `http://admin.domain.com/_admin/tst`

how to fix it so `/_admin` is hidden?

Comment: could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you report seems to follow your configuration closely. What is the expected result that you're not getting?

If you want to redirect `domain.com/page` to `www.domain.com/page` instead of `www.domain.com/domain.com/page`, which seems sensible, remove this block:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      !^/domain\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /domain.com/$1 [L]
```

Comment: it's still the same.. you are redirected to domain.com/domain.com

Comment: I want to rewrite www.domain.com/domain.com/page to www.domain.com/page..